# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem regarding dropdown.From my code the dropdown value from database is displayed. But when I do not fill any values and press enter the error of There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable displays.

Following are my codes:

**Category.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace BusinessLayer
{

    public interface ICategory
    {
         int CategoryId { get; set; }
         string CategoryDescription { get; set; }

    }
    public class Category:ICategory
    {
         [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
       [Required]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public SelectList CategoryList { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

**CategoryBusinessLayer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BusinessLayer
{
   public class CategoryBusinessLayer
    {
        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories
        {
            get
            {
                string connectionString =
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCSS"].ConnectionString;

                List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllCategory", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Category categories = new Category();
                        categories.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CategoryId"]);
                        categories.CategoryName = rdr["CategoryName"].ToString();
                        categories.CategoryDescription = rdr["CategoryDescription"].ToString();
                        categoryList.Add(categories);
                    }
                }

                return categoryList;
            }
        }
}
```

**ProductController.cs**

```
 [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("Create")]
        public ActionResult Create_Get()
        {
            Category category = new Category();
            CategoryBusinessLayer cat = new CategoryBusinessLayer();
            category.CategoryList = new SelectList(cat.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
            ViewBag.category = category.CategoryList;
            return View();
        }
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
  @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.category as SelectList, "Select Category")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you submit the form and your HttpPost action method is returning the same view without reloading the ViewData items which is needed to build the SELECT element.

In your GET and POST actions, you may simply set a list of `SelectListItem` to the ViewBag/ViewData. Also your current code is unnecessarily doing the casting twice! in the view with this expression

```
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.category as SelectList
```

Make sure you reload this data before returning the same view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SomeViewModel model)
{

   // your existing code to get category 
   ViewBag.category = category.CategoryList
                              .Select(x=> new SelectListItem { Value=x.Id,
                                                     Text= x.CategoryName }).ToList();
   return View(model);
}
```

Now in your view,

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", ViewBag.category as List<SelectListItem>,
                                                                       "Select Category")
```